# What is the fastest way to $\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, big-list, pi, convergence-acceleration

There are many known sequences convergent to $\pi$ with different convergence accelerations. For example both of the following sequences are convergent to $\pi$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$:

**(a)** $a_n=2^{n+1}\times\sqrt{2-\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2}}}}}}}$ which the under brace part repeats $n$ times. More clear:

$a_0=2\sqrt{2}$

$a_1=4\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$

$a_2=8\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$

$a_3=16\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}$

$...$

**(b)** $b_n=4\times\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}$

More clear:

$b_0=4$

$b_1=4(1-\frac{1}{3})$

$b_2=4(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5})$

$b_3=4(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7})$

$...$

It seems the first sequence goes to $\pi$ faster than the second one.

**Question:** What is the fastest known explicit sequence convergent to $\pi$? Please introduce a list of known sequences convergent to $\pi$ and their convergence accelerations.

Comment: How about $\pi, \pi,\pi,...$? (Hmm, I'm hungry now.)

Comment: There is a huge literature. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80) will give a start.

Comment: @copper.hat: Cool answer! :-)

Comment: Some good series that converge at an exponential rate can be found here: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/monthly567-587.pdf

Answer (score 8):

The fastest (by **steps/iterations**) is [Gauss - Legendre algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm) (see [AGM method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGM_method) too) and its modifications.

$25$ iterations to get  $45$ million correct digits of $\pi$...

But this algorithm is very expansive in time, because each step uses square root calculating (very-very slow operation for huge number of digits).

**Release A:** (by Brent $-$ Salamin, modification) :

\begin{array}{llll}
a_0 = 1, & b_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, & u_0 = 0, & v_0 = 1;\\
a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}, &
b_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n b_n}, &
u_{n+1} = \frac{u_n+v_n}{2}, &
v_{n+1} = \frac{a_nv_n+b_nu_n}{2b_{n+1}}
\end{array}
and
$$
\pi_n = 2\sqrt{2} \frac{a_n^3}{v_n}  \approx \pi.
$$

First steps:

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|r|}\hline
n & p_n & \pi-p_n & \log_{10}(\pi-p_n) \\
\hline0) & \color{gray}{2.828427...} & 3.13165... \times 10^{-1} &  -0.50422... \\
1) & \color{gray}{2.95807...} & 1.83515... \times 10^{-1} &  -0.73632... \\
2) & \underline{3.14}\color{gray}{066686...}  & 9.25783... \times 10^{-4} &  -3.03349... \\
3) & \underline{3.1415926}\color{gray}{465191...}  & 7.07059...\times 10^{-9} & -8.15054... \\
4) & \underline{3.141592653589793238}\color{gray}{28322...} & 1.79413... \times 10^{-19} & -18.74614... \\
5) & \small{\underline{3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971}\color{gray}{15228...}} & 5.41713... \times 10^{-41} & -40.26623... \\
6) & ... & 2.39409...\times 10^{-84} & -83.62085... 
\end{array}

Each iteration **multiplies** number of correct digits by $\approx 2$.

**Release B:** (by Brent $-$ Salamin):

\begin{array}{llll}
a_0 = 1, & b_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, & t_0 = \frac{1}{4};\\
a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}, &
b_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n b_n}, &
t_{n+1} = t_n-2^n(a_n-a_{n+1})^2, &
\end{array}
and
$$
\pi_n = \frac{(a_n+b_n)^2}{4t_n} \approx \pi.
$$

First steps:

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|r|}\hline
n & p_n & \pi-p_n & \log_{10}(\pi-p_n) \\
\hline0) & \color{gray}{2.91421...} & 2.27379... \times 10^{-1} &  -0.64324... \\
1) & \underline{3.14}\color{gray}{05792...} & 1.01340... \times 10^{-3} &  -2.99421... \\
2) & \underline{3.1415926}\color{gray}{46213...}  & 7.37625... \times 10^{-9} &  -8.13216... \\
3) & \underline{3.141592653589793238}\color{gray}{27951...}  & 1.83130...\times 10^{-19} & -18.73723... \\
4) & \small{\underline{3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971}\color{gray}{14678...}} & 5.47210... \times 10^{-41} & -40.26184... \\
5) & ... & 2.40612... \times 10^{-84} & -83.61868...
\end{array}

Each iteration multiplies number of correct digits by $\approx 2$.

**Release C:** (by Borwein brothers) : (see http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~jborwein/Kanada_50b.html):

\begin{array}{ll}
y_0 = \sqrt{2}-1, & a_0 = 6-4\sqrt{2};\\
y_{n+1} = \frac{1-\sqrt[4]{1-y_n^4}}{1+\sqrt[4]{1-y_n^4}}, &
a_{n+1} = (1+y_{n+1})^4a_n - 2^{2n+3}(1+y_{n+1}+y_{n+1}^2), &
\end{array}
and
$$
\pi_n = \frac{1}{a_n} \approx \pi.
$$

First steps:

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|r|}
\hline
n & p_n & \pi-p_n & \log_{10}(\pi-p_n) \\
\hline
0) & \color{gray}{2.91421...} & 2.27379... \times 10^{-1} &  -0.64324... \\
1) & \underline{3.1415926}\color{gray}{46213...} & 7.37625... \times 10^{-9} &  -8.13216... \\
2) & \small{\underline{3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971}\color{gray}{14678...}} & 5.47210... \times 10^{-41} & -40.26184... \\
3) & ... & 2.30858... \times 10^{-171} & -170.63665...
\end{array}

Each iteration multiplies number of correct digits by $\approx 4$ (in fact, it is interlined release B).

---

Collection of such algorithms: http://www.pi314.net/eng/algo.php.

---

But, in general, there are no "the fastest" sequence, because if the sequence $\{s_n\}$ converges very fast, then the sequence $\{t_n\}$, where $t_n= s_{2n}$ converges faster.

Answer (score 4):

The provably fastest convergence, in fractions, is given by the [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Motivation_and_notation):

$$[3;7,15,1,292,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,\ldots]$$

This corresponds to the sequence $$3,\frac{22}{7}, \frac{333}{106}, \frac{355}{113}, \frac{103993}{33102},\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

One of the astounding formulae for $\pi$ is surely 
https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/ramanujan.html